# Relational Division Issue to Solve for Total

Tags: t-sql

I have a table of Card holders and the amount of each cards they have.
I'm trying to query to get a result of Full Card Set holders and how many sets they each have.
The data is simular to below:

**Cards **

| Card | User | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 1234 | 2 |
| BB | 1234 | 2 |
| CC | 1234 | 2 |
| DD | 1234 | 1 |
| AA | 4321 | 1 |
| BB | 4321 | 1 |
| CC | 4321 | 1 |
| AA | 3321 | 3 |
| BB | 2221 | 1 |
| CC | 2221 | 4 |

**Card Sets **

| Card | Set |
| --- | --- |
| AA | SetA |
| BB | SetA |
| CC | SetA |

If looking for "SetA" I would expect below.

**Results **

| User | TotalSets |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2 |
| 4321 | 1 |

I know this is possibly a Relational Division solution but not sure how to get the count of sets per Card Holder.

This is what I was using before I needed total sets:

```
`SELECT
  cs.[Set],
  tc.User
  FROM Cards tc
JOIN (
      SELECT *,
            Total = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CardSets.[Set])
                FROM CardSets cs
) ts ON tc.Card = cs.Card
GROUP BY
  cs.[Set], tc.User
  HAVING COUNT(*) = MIN(cs.Total);`
```

Comment: Sounds like something along the lines of: (Distinct User) cross join (Card Sets) left join Cards group by (User, Set) select Min(isnull(Count,0)) AS Sets, then group by User and select sum(Sets) as TotalSets. But that is just a first guess. Coding it up and giving it a try will be the test.

Comment: If a user 5678 had lines with (Card,Count)=('AA',1),('BB',2),('CC',3) what shoud their TotalSets be?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis they would have 1 Total Set

Comment: Updated my question to show was I was using before I needed total sets

Answer (score 0):

A blind try, please provide us a `create table/insert script` for convenience:

```
select
     c.[user]
    ,cs.[set]
    
    -- if any cs row
    ,fullsets=
     min(case when c.card is null then 0 else 1 end) -- if card missing for a set, set this flag to 0 to absorb results
     *
     min(c.[count])
from 
    cardsets cs
    left join cards c on c.card=cs.card -- if a card belongs to multiple sets, you'll need to add here: and cs.[set]='SetA'
group by c.[user],cs.[set]
```